How to pass values into the "LWC CRM Analytics Dashboard" component?
I'd like to use a CRM Analytics dashboard filtered by values from the page it is contained in e.g. the record ID from a details page.
The "LWC CRM Analytics Dashboard" component (screen shot below from the "Lightning App Builder") has a "Filter" property with "i" text of:

Create dashboard filters in the Filter Builder, or enter a JSON string. This property supports using an expression to define its custom label. The correct format is {!$Label.customLabelName}.


Question 1
Is the JSON format this as described in the "filters JSON" section of the Analytics Dashboard JSON
Developer Guide (this example using Salesforce Objects directly not through a dataset):
        "filters": [
            [
                "Type__c",
                [
                    "Energy"
                ],
                "in"
            ]
        ]

or something else?
Question 2
I don't see a way to inject context from the containing page e.g. for a record detail page the record ID. Is there a way to do that?

Just found this Embed Dashboards in Lightning Pages linked from the Analytics Templates Developer
Guide. It does indicate that for LWC the filter input is JSON only (there is a "Filter Builder" button for Aura) and includes this documentation link of Syntax Reference Tables
.
So think this answers question 1.
No sign of a way to inject context from the containing page, so I think the answer to question 2 is no.
